# Python - Group by over dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I am using Python 3.5 and I have the following array of dics:

```
d1 = [{id=1, col="name", oldvalue="foo", newvalue="bar"}, {id=1, col="age", oldvalue="25", newvalue="26"}, {id=2, col="name", oldvalue="foo", newvalue="foobar"}, {id=3, col="age", oldvalue="25", newvalue="26"}]

d2 = [{id=1, col="name", oldvalue="foo", newvalue="bar"}, {id=1, col="age", oldvalue="25"]

d3 = [{id=3, col="age", oldvalue="25", newvalue="26"}]
```

As you can see it is showing some changes made to particular "rows".

I want to know if there is a way to return the total of rows updated, so:

```
def counting_updates(d):
    # ...
    return total

print counting_updates(d1) # prints 3 because 3 rows were updated
print counting_updates(d2) # prints 1 because 1 row was updated
print counting_updates(d3) # prints 1 because 1 row was updated
```

Comment: Are the `id`s the rows or the `col`s?

Comment: Each row is a dictionary, and id would be the primary key

Comment: use a list comprehension: `sum(item['oldvalue'] != item['newvalue'] for item in d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the number of unique `id`s, then

```
len({row['id'] for row in d})
```

The `{}` is a set comprehension.